# Read String Array Fom XML into VBA

Tags: asp.net, xml, string, vba, web-services

I have the Following XML which is a result from a certain WEB-Service.

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<ArrayOfString xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<string>16/May/2016 - 20/May/2016</string>

<string>20/May/2016 - 23/May/2016</string>

<string>23/May/2016 - 27/May/2016</string>

<string>27/May/2016 - 30/May/2016</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

I have the Following VBA Code to read the Above XML

```
    strRet = PostWebservice(strUrlEBenefit, strSoapAction, strXml)
    intPos1 = InStr(strRet, "<string>") + 8
    intPos2 = InStr(strRet, "</string>")

    If intPos1 > 11 And intPos2 > 0 Then
        xmlresult = Mid(strRet, intPos1, intPos2 - intPos1)
    End If
```

as a result I'm Getting "16/May/2016 - 20/May/2016" in xmlresult.

What I want to do is getting all the date values Between all the [string] tags.
Can you please guide me how can I achieve the result? I understand I need to read it into array but I don't know how and didn't saw any useful tutorials for me(beginner in VBA and XML) to ref.

Answer (score 1):

Read the xml-result which was returned from the web service into xml-document and use e.g. `SelectSingleNode` to select the node `ArrayOfString`. This node has namaspaces so you need to use namespaces in the `xpath` as well. Then just read all the child node texts e.g. into a collection here declared as `result`. HTH

*Note: Add reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0 dll*

```
Sub GetDateValues()
    Dim xmlDocument As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlNamespaces As String
    Dim arrayOfStringNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim result As Collection
    Dim xmlNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim strRet As String

    strRet = PostWebservice(strUrlEBenefit, strSoapAction, strXml)
    Set xmlDocument = New DOMDocument60

    If Not xmlDocument.LoadXML(strRet) Then
        Err.Raise xmlDocument.parseError.ErrorCode, , xmlDocument.parseError.reason
    End If

    xmlNamespaces = "xmlns:myns='http://tempuri.org/'"
    xmlDocument.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNamespaces
    Set arrayOfStringNode = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/myns:ArrayOfString")
    Set result = New Collection

    For Each xmlNode In arrayOfStringNode.ChildNodes
        result.Add xmlNode.Text
    Next xmlNode
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm extrapolating using the answer from: 'dee', but reading in to an array with x number of columns. The reason for dNode below is because webservices often return auxiliary metadata at the same level as the actual value you want in your array. So you have to use SelectSingleNode at that point.

```
xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNamespaces
Set xmlNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/myns:.../...")
rws = xmlNodes.length
cols = var '# of columns from the request sent or extrapolate this code to count children of a single node at the level necessary
ReDim xay(1 To rws, 1 To cols)

For Each xNode In xmlNodes
    r = r + 1
    For c = 1 To UBound(xay, 2)
        Set dNode = xNode.ChildNodes(c - 1)
        Set dNode = dNode.SelectSingleNode("myns:THE_VALUE")
        xay(r, c) = dNode.Text
    Next c
Next xNode
```